# using nsfwjs in php project for local files

Tags: javascript

I have looked up nsfwjs for implementing it in my php Project
but there syntax is uncomprehensive there js has no semicolons and lots of starange things please do a complete explanation on using nsfwjs for pictures locally

I have tried there given format but dont know which frame work is this

```
--Code--
import * as nsfwjs from 'nsfwjs'

const img = document.getElementById('img')

// Load model from my S3.
// See the section hosting the model files on your site.
const model = await nsfwjs.load()

// Classify the image
const predictions = await model.classify(img)
console.log('Predictions: ', predictions)
--error I am getting--

  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

Comment: Are you trying to run ECMAScript in PHP? This will not work :)

Comment: will node.js work ?

Comment: Yes, it will work :)

Comment: which programming languages are best for backend should I learn only node.js will it replace all python etc

Comment: Hey, there is no such thing as best language. Languages are like tools, you have to decide which tool suite you problem best. Every programming language has its pros and cons :)